# Is there a way to create non-bordered transparent windows in Python?

Tags: python, user-interface, widget

I am trying to make a widget-style application in Python, and I have tried searching around but I have not found a GUI toolkit that allows you to hide borders and remove the window background (fully transparent, only content rendered).

Is there a *Python GUI toolkit* with the following features?:

- No window borders.
- Completely transparent background.
- Non-OS specific GUI control rendering (custom bitmaps, fonts, etc).
- Event Detection (click, keyboard, etc)
- Window Management (always on top, steal focus, etc)

Comment: Window borders and transparency are handled by the window manager. I don't think there is any cross-platform way of removing them (though I could be wrong). You could write a KDE plasma widget, but that's a lot of baggage for one widget.

Comment: Window borders are drawn by the window manager, but there's a standard way to request that they be drawn, or not.  If there wasn't, then it would be impossible for a GUI toolkit to do something as basic as show a pop-up menu!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, [wxpython](http://wxpython.org/) can do this. Look at the ShapedWindow example in the Demo application (available on the download page). [image]

Answer (score 1):

It's been a little while since I've done things like that, but I would think that most GUI toolkits would allow you to do that.  For example, GTK+ has Python bindings, and should support all of that.

[Here's an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3908565/how-to-make-gtk-window-background-transparent) of using GTK+ to draw transparent content with GUI controls.

I have even less experience with them, but I think wxWidgets and Qt/KDE have similar functionality.