# Draw text on screen python?

Tags: python, string, text, graphics, draw

Is there anyway to draw pure text over the desktop? I'd like to draw text on the screen, without having the user be able to interact with it. An idea would maybe be to make a fullscreen window with a transparent background and frame, write the text in the window, and make it so the user cannot focus the window. I have no idea how to go about this, and if anyone could point me in the right direction that'd be great :D

TL;DR
 Is there anyway to draw text over the desktop without using a window?

Comment: you would need a module. Like turtle can draw text but only in the window. I don't think there is any inherent way to just draw text  anywhere though.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9407681/6877504 Would this be what you are looking for?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to create non-bordered transperant windows in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5158295/is-there-a-way-to-create-non-bordered-transperant-windows-in-python)