# How do I make a gtkwindow background transparent on Linux?

Tags: gtk, gtk3

I would like to make the background transparent, and only the widgets are visible.

Here is my code:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    gtk_init (&argc, &argv);
    GtkWidget *window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);

    // Title
    gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW (window), "Transparency");
    //gtk_window_set_opacity(GTK_WINDOW(window), 0.5);

    // CSS
    GtkCssProvider *provider = gtk_css_provider_new();
    GdkDisplay *display = gdk_display_get_default();
    GdkScreen *screen = gdk_display_get_default_screen(display);
    gtk_style_context_add_provider_for_screen(screen, GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER (provider), GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_USER);
    gtk_css_provider_load_from_data(GTK_CSS_PROVIDER (provider),
                                    "GtkWindow {\n"
                                    "   background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);\n"
                                    "}\n",
                                     -1, NULL);
    g_object_unref (provider);

    // Window
    gtk_window_set_position(GTK_WINDOW(window), GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER);
    gtk_window_resize(GTK_WINDOW(window), 400, 300);
    gtk_widget_show_all(window);

    gtk_main();
    return 0;
}
```

I use gtk3. When the program execute, it just shows black. The CSS (or rgba) function does not work.
I try to use gtk_window_set_opacity(), but it also just shows black.
How do I fix my code?

Comment: Use cairo instead, please see this thread. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3908565/how-to-make-gtk-window-background-transparent

Answer (score 16):

I followed the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3908565/how-to-make-gtk-window-background-transparent) suggested by the comment, but unfortunately it was written for Gtk 2. I have re-worked it for Gtk 3. (I am using Gtk 3.8, but as far as I know it does not use anything deprecated in Gtk 3.10). The program produces a green semi-transparent square with button in it. Of course, you could make the square completely transparent by changing the last argument for the function `cairo_set_source_rgba` to 0.

Note: I compiled this with the following command (assuming you call the file `transparent.c`):

```
gcc -o transparent transparent.c `pkg-config gtk+-3.0 --libs --cflags`
```

Here is the code:

## Version for C

```c
/**
 * Original code by: Mike - http://plan99.net/~mike/blog (now a dead link--unable to find it).
 * Modified by karlphillip for StackExchange:
 *     (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3908565/how-to-make-gtk-window-background-transparent)
 * Re-worked for Gtk 3 by Louis Melahn, L.C., January 30, 2014.
 */

#include <gtk/gtk.h>

static void screen_changed(GtkWidget *widget, GdkScreen *old_screen, gpointer user_data);
static gboolean draw(GtkWidget *widget, cairo_t *new_cr, gpointer user_data);
static void clicked(GtkWindow *win, GdkEventButton *event, gpointer user_data);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    GtkWidget *window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_window_set_position(GTK_WINDOW(window), GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER);
    gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 400, 400);
    gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), "Alpha Demo");
    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(window), "delete-event", gtk_main_quit, NULL);

    gtk_widget_set_app_paintable(window, TRUE);

    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(window), "draw", G_CALLBACK(draw), NULL);
    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(window), "screen-changed", G_CALLBACK(screen_changed), NULL);

    gtk_window_set_decorated(GTK_WINDOW(window), FALSE);
    gtk_widget_add_events(window, GDK_BUTTON_PRESS_MASK);
    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(window), "button-press-event", G_CALLBACK(clicked), NULL);

    GtkWidget* fixed_container = gtk_fixed_new();
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), fixed_container);
    GtkWidget* button = gtk_button_new_with_label("button1");
    gtk_widget_set_size_request(button, 100, 100);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(fixed_container), button);

    screen_changed(window, NULL, NULL);

    gtk_widget_show_all(window);
    gtk_main();

    return 0;
}

gboolean supports_alpha = FALSE;
static void screen_changed(GtkWidget *widget, GdkScreen *old_screen, gpointer userdata)
{
    /* To check if the display supports alpha channels, get the visual */
    GdkScreen *screen = gtk_widget_get_screen(widget);
    GdkVisual *visual = gdk_screen_get_rgba_visual(screen);

    if (!visual)
    {
        printf("Your screen does not support alpha channels!\n");
        visual = gdk_screen_get_system_visual(screen);
        supports_alpha = FALSE;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Your screen supports alpha channels!\n");
        supports_alpha = TRUE;
    }

    gtk_widget_set_visual(widget, visual);
}

static gboolean draw(GtkWidget *widget, cairo_t *cr, gpointer userdata)
{
    cairo_save (cr);

    if (supports_alpha)
    {
        cairo_set_source_rgba (cr, 0.5, 1.0, 0.50, 0.5); /* transparent */
    }
    else
    {
        cairo_set_source_rgb (cr, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0); /* opaque white */
    }

    /* draw the background */
    cairo_set_operator (cr, CAIRO_OPERATOR_SOURCE);
    cairo_paint (cr);

    cairo_restore (cr);

    return FALSE;
}

static void clicked(GtkWindow *win, GdkEventButton *event, gpointer user_data)
{
    /* toggle window manager frames */
    gtk_window_set_decorated(win, !gtk_window_get_decorated(win));
}
```

## Version for C++

I include a very similar program, this time written for `gtkmm` in C++. It can be compiled with the following command:

```
g++ -otransparent main.cpp transparent.cpp `pkg-config gtkmm-3.0 --cflags --libs` -std=c++11
```

Note that I used some of the features in the new C++-11 standard, so you will need a compiler that supports them. (If you don't have one, you just have to replace the `auto` keyword when it appears with the appropriate type, which  you can figure out from the definition of the function.) There are three files: `main.cpp`, `transparent.h`, and `transparent.cpp`.

### main.cpp

/**
     * main.cpp
     *
     * Code adapted from 'alphademo.c' by Mike
     * (http://plan99.net/~mike/blog--now a dead link--unable to find it.)
     * as modified by karlphillip for StackExchange:
     *     (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3908565/how-to-make-gtk-window-background-transparent)
     * Re-worked for Gtkmm 3.0 by Louis Melahn, L.C. January 31, 2014.
     */
    #include "transparent.h"
    #include 
    
    int main (int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        Glib::RefPtr app = Gtk::Application::create(argc, argv, "org.gtkmm.example.transparent");
    
        Transparent transparent;
    
        //Shows the window and returns when it is closed.
        return app->run(transparent);
    }

### transparent.h

```cpp
/**
 * transparent.h
 *
 * Code adapted from 'alphademo.c' by Mike
 * (http://plan99.net/~mike/blog--now a dead link--unable to find it.)
 * as modified by karlphillip for StackExchange:
 *     (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3908565/how-to-make-gtk-window-background-transparent)
 * Re-worked for Gtkmm 3.0 by Louis Melahn, L.C. January 31, 2014.
 */

#ifndef TRANSPARENT_H_
#define TRANSPARENT_H_

#include <iostream>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <gtkmm/window.h>
#include <gtkmm/button.h>
#include <gtkmm/alignment.h>

class Transparent : public Gtk::Window
{

private:
    std::string _buttonLabel;

public:
    Transparent();
    void set_visual(Glib::RefPtr<Gdk::Visual> visual);
    virtual ~Transparent();

protected:
    // Signal handlers:
    // Note that on_draw is actually overriding a virtual function
    // from the Gtk::Window class. I set it as virtual here in case
    // someone wants to override it again in a derived class.
    void on_button_clicked();
    virtual bool on_draw(const ::Cairo::RefPtr< ::Cairo::Context>& cr);
    void on_screen_changed(const Glib::RefPtr<Gdk::Screen>& previous_screen);
    bool on_window_clicked(GdkEventButton* event);

    // Member widgets:
    Gtk::Alignment _alignment;
    Gtk::Button _button;

    bool _SUPPORTS_ALPHA = false;

};

#endif /* TRANSPARENT_H_ */
```

### transparent.cpp

```cpp
/**
 * transparent.cpp
 *
 * Code adapted from 'alphademo.c' by Mike
 * (http://plan99.net/~mike/blog--now a dead link--unable to find it.)
 * as modified by karlphillip for StackExchange:
 *     (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3908565/how-to-make-gtk-window-background-transparent)
 * Re-worked for Gtkmm 3.0 by Louis Melahn, L.C. January 31, 2014.
 */
#include "transparent.h"

Transparent::Transparent() :
    _buttonLabel("Button1"),
    _alignment(Gtk::ALIGN_START, Gtk::ALIGN_START, 0.0, 0.0),    // Aligns the button.
    _button(_buttonLabel)                                        // Creates a new button with label '_buttonLabel'.
{

    // Set up the top-level window.
    set_title("Transparency test");
    set_default_size(400,400);
    set_decorated(false);
    add_events(Gdk::BUTTON_PRESS_MASK);
    set_position(Gtk::WIN_POS_CENTER);
    set_app_paintable(true);

    // Signal handlers
    signal_draw().connect(sigc::mem_fun(*this, &Transparent::on_draw));
    signal_screen_changed().connect(sigc::mem_fun(*this, &Transparent::on_screen_changed));
    signal_button_press_event().connect(sigc::mem_fun(*this, &Transparent::on_window_clicked));
    _button.signal_clicked().connect(sigc::mem_fun(*this, &Transparent::on_button_clicked));

    // Widgets

    on_screen_changed(get_screen());

    // This will add the aligner.
    add(_alignment);

    // Now pack the button into the aligner.
    _alignment.add(_button);

    // Set up the button
    _button.set_size_request(100, 100);

    // Show the window and all its children.
    show_all();
}

Transparent::~Transparent()
{
}

void Transparent::on_button_clicked()
{
    std::cout << "The button '" << _buttonLabel << "' was pressed." << std::endl;
}

bool Transparent::on_draw(const Cairo::RefPtr<Cairo::Context>& cr)
{
    cr->save();
    if (_SUPPORTS_ALPHA) {
        cr->set_source_rgba(0.5, 1.0, 0.5, 0.5);    // transparent
    } else {
        cr->set_source_rgb(0.5, 1.0, 0.5);          // opaque
    }
    cr->set_operator(Cairo::OPERATOR_SOURCE);
    cr->paint();
    cr->restore();

    return Gtk::Window::on_draw(cr);
}

/**
 * Checks to see if the display supports alpha channels
 */
void Transparent::on_screen_changed(const Glib::RefPtr<Gdk::Screen>& previous_screen) {
    auto screen = get_screen();
    auto visual = screen->get_rgba_visual();

    if (!visual) {
        std::cout << "Your screen does not support alpha channels!" << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "Your screen supports alpha channels!" << std::endl;
        _SUPPORTS_ALPHA = TRUE;
    }

    set_visual(visual);
}

/**
 * This simply adds a method which seems to be missing in Gtk::Widget,
 * so I had to use Gtk+ manually.
 *
 * Sets the visual for 'this' (the current widget).
 */
void Transparent::set_visual(Glib::RefPtr<Gdk::Visual> visual) {
    gtk_widget_set_visual(GTK_WIDGET(gobj()), visual->gobj());
}

/**
 * If I click somewhere other than the button, this toggles
 * between having window decorations and not having them.
 */
bool Transparent::on_window_clicked(GdkEventButton* event) {
    set_decorated(!get_decorated());
    return false;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. I don't think creating a new cairo surface is needed, though.
You can just use the default one (using _save and _restore).

Comment: Original link is available on the wayback machine! https://web.archive.org/web/20121027002505/http://plan99.net/~mike/files/alphademo.c

Answer (score 9):

While struggling with the same issue, I have noticed that if I call gtk_window_set_opacity() on the toplevel window **after** the show_all function, making the whole window (partial) transparent works for me. Give this a try:

```
gtk_widget_show_all ( window );
gtk_widget_set_opacity (GTK_WIDGET (window), 0.5);
```

Does that work for you too?

Comment: this worked for me on python as well using `self.window.set_opacity(0.5)` after `self.window.show_all()`

Comment: Great answer, it worked for me in C++ with just `gtk_widget_set_opacity(widget, 0.5)`. But be aware that if you set opacity level from GLADE it wont work. In my case I tried with opacity option from GLADE but didn't work. So I set opacity level in GLADE to 1 and change it from C++.