# Make GTK2 Window transparent

Tags: c, linux, gtk

I am trying to make a window with no decoration and transparent background using gtk2. What I have found so far does not work for me, this includes this:
[How to make Gtk+ window background transparent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3908565/how-to-make-gtk-window-background-transparent)

Somehow I still have a white background.

What Ive done is make the gtk undecorated, set the colormap in the screen change event like in the example and draw it transparent in the expose event. Even the demo from the post above is not working.